# How do I add a curve or arc to a diagram on draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I have looked through all the available items but cannot find a curve or arc to add to my diagram. Is it there somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a curved connector, you can find that in the general shapes section:

[image: The general shapes library of the diagrams.net interface with the curved connector highlighted as a tooltip]

Once the curve is in the editor, you can add and drag the waypoints of the curve. Select the curve and waypoints appear as blue handles:

[image: The curved connector selected in the draw.io interface]

The basic shapes library contains both arc and pie shape (near the bottom). If you drag those into the editor and select them, both have orange handles (indicating you can alter the shape), these allow you to change the angle around which each shape is drawn:

[image: The arc shape in diagrams.net and draw.io selected on the editor interface. It shows two orange handles at the ends of the arc that can be dragged to alter the arc dimensions]

[image: The pie shape in diagrams.net and draw.io selected on the editor interface. It shows two orange handles at the ends of the pie that can be dragged to alter the pie dimensions]

If none of those options work, there is also a freehand mode where you could draw a freehand curve:

[image: The draw.io interface showing the insert menu with freehand mode highlighted]

Comment: You can also select one of those curved lines and click on the right sidebar button "Set as Default Style" to always use the curved shape. I think it's prettier.

Comment: The curve shape has too many non-removable bendable points, it's not possible to create a simple arc, it bends in too many ways.

Answer (score 14):

A more manual approach to getting curves in draw.io, is to edit the shape of some element. This allows for three different variations of curves,  `<arc ... />`, `<quad ... />` or `<curve ... />`. The image show these three curves, and further down is the code needed to produce these elements. The image has some extra guidelines to help illustrate the curve generation.

[image: Example image of arc, quad and curve]

### Modifying shapes

We are able to edit the style and shape of elements within draw.io. Not all elements does however have a shape to be edited. Most of the elements in the *Basic* menu does have a shape to edited.

Shape and style can edited from the *Format Panel* <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> in the *Style* tab, and there you have some buttons aptly named *Edit Style*, *Edit Image*, and/or *Edit Shape*. Which buttons are showing depends on the selected element.

For this answer we're focusing on the *Edit Shape* button, and to display it we start by adding a *Basic > Star* to our drawing. Draw.io has some documentation on [editing shapes](//support.draw.io/display/DO/Editing+Shapes) with a [small example](//gist.githubusercontent.com/alderg/9fe52ddb8b2185fb7daa/raw/a962bdaf1229186f6ee60cd5225ccc420ac58f0a/gistfile1.txt), and a reference to the SVG documentation on [drawing arcs](//www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands), which was the basis for me experimenting until I found the code examples used in this answer.

For each of the examples below, insert some element with a shape, select it and click the *Edit Shape* button. Insert or edit the text within and either hit *Preview* for a preview, or *Apply* to close the dialog and see your final result. The final result of this code, with some added guidelines results in this image:

### Edit an `arc`

The arc is the based upon two ellipses which goes through the base point, and the specificed point. As these actually form four different paths from the base to the end point, you have to chose which of these paths you are using.

Here is example code for a pie segment of 240°:

```
<shape aspect="variable" h="2.0" w="2.0" name="Angle" strokewidth="inherit">
  <connections/>
  <background>
    <path>
      <move x="2.0" y="1.0"/>
      <arc x="0.5" y="1.866" rx="1.0" ry="1.0" large-arc-flag="1" sweep-flag="0" x-axis-rotation="0"/>
      <line x="1.0" y="1.0"/>
      <close/>
    </path>
  </background>  
  <foreground>
    <fillstroke/>
  </foreground>
</shape>
```

Here are the details as to why this code draws a pie segmennt of 240 degrees:

- Most shapes will need to have `shape`, `background` and/or `foreground`. When I chose to use `background` it is because that allows me to add shadows to the shape very easily. I've made the base canvas of the shape to be a square of height and width equals 2.0, this is to allow for a full unit circle to be included within the shape
- We need to draw a `path`

  - We'll start at 0 degrees, which translates into the `<move x="2.0" y="1.0">` command
  - We then draw an `arc` going from the previous point in path till an end point `(x, y)`, with radiuses of the ellipsises (`rx` and `ry`) where `sweep-flag` and `large-arc-flag` selects the correct ellipse part, and whether these ellipsises are rotated (`x-axis-rotation`). To get a 240 degree we need the following:

    - Using basic trig or an [Interactive Unit Circle](//www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-interactive-unit-circle.html) we find the coordinates on the unit circle corresponding to 240 degrees: `(cos(240°), sin(240°) = (-0.5, -0.866)` which translated into our shape needs to be `(1+x, 1-y)` which gives `x="0.5" y="1.866"`
    - The degree is larger than 180, so we choose `large-arc-flag="1"`
    - And we are drawing the path anti-clockwise, which gives `sweep-flag="0"`
  - To make it a nice pie segment, we add a `line` back to the center, coordinates `1.0, 1.0`, and then `close` the path
- This defines the entire path, which is going to get a shadow, but it has strictly speaking not been drawn yet. This is done using the `fillstroke` command in the `foreground` section

Note that if you only want the arc segment, you can drop the `line` and `close` tags, and replace the `fillstroke` with a simple `stroke`. Do experiment with changing the `sweep-flag`and `large-arc-flag`, and the other tags. In my example I've used `rx=ry=1` which transform the ellipsis into circles, but do experiment with change the radius, sweep or large-arc stuff, and see what happens.

Some other coordinates to get some standard angles are as follows:

- 45° on unit circle: `(0.707, 0.707)` which gives `x="1.707" y="0.293"`
- 60° on unit circle: `(0.5, 0.866)` which gives `x="1.5" y="0.134"`
- 225° = 180°+45° : `(-0.707, -0.707)` which gives `x="0.293" y="1.707"`
- n° on unit circle: `(cos(n)`, sin(n)`` which gives `x="1+cos(n)" y="1-sin(n)"`
- Note the values `0.707` (& `0.293`), `0.5`, `0.866` (& `0.134`), which reoccurs regularly related to the 30°, 45° & 60° and `n*90°` angles around the circle...

Note the use of `move` to specify the base point, and then the daisy chaining of `arc` and `line` (and you could have used `quad` and `curve`) to produce a longer path.

### Edit an `quad`

An `quad` curve is a quadratic curve, which is the curve you get when starting with a line from base point through control point, and turn around till you match the line from the control point through end point.

Here is an example:

```
<shape aspect="variable" h="1" w="1" name="Quad" strokewidth="inherit">
  <connections />
  <background>
    <path>
      <move x="0" y="0"/>
      <quad x1="0.25" y1="1" x2="1" y2="1"/>
    </path>
  </background>
  <foreground>
    <stroke/>
  </foreground>
</shape>
```

Explanation of `quad` curve:

- Set the base point, `<move x="0" y="0" />`
- Give a control point to the `quad`, `x1="0.25" y1="1"`
- And specify the end point, `x2="1" y2="1"`

This kind of curve can be useful when you want to control the angle of the start and end line segments of the curve. That is, if you want to make multiple curve segments, and want them to have nice joints.

### Edit a `curve`

The final `curve` shape, are using two control point which kind of works as gravitational pulls on the line until the end point. Here is the code:

```
<shape aspect="variable" h="1" w="1" name="curve" strokewidth="inherit">
  <connections />
  <background>
    <path>
      <move x="0" y="0"/>
      <curve x1="0.1" y1="0.4" x2="0.9" y2="0.3" x3="1" y3="1"/>
    </path>
  </background>
  <foreground>
    <stroke/>
  </foreground>
</shape>
```

- Set the base point, `<move x="0" y="0" />`
- Give two control points to the `curve`, `x1="0.1" y1="0.4" x2="0.9" y2="0.3"`
- And specify the end point, `x3="1" y3="1"`

Note that I've used the upper left as start point, and lower right as end point for both the `quad` and the `curve`, this can of course be changed if you want another general direction of the curve.

Comment: Where do I enter this code? All I can find is a button called "Edit Style", but when I press it I get code on the form `ellipse;whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;aspect=fixed;fillColor=#FF6666;fontColor=#FFFFFF;`, and when I paste your code in there instead, I break the shape and I can't see it anymore.

Comment: Menu bar -> Extras -> Create Shape

Comment: `Arrange->Insert->Shape...` worked for me. I didn't understand how to find the "Edit shape" in drawio 13.0.3

Answer (score 1):

One of the way to draw arcs is drag the Bidirectional curve from the Misc panel to the drawing area and then click on the curve to see the "blue colored" points known as "waypoints". You can remove these waypoints to alter its structure. Right click and select remove waypoint. Remove unnecessary way points until you have only 3 way points , 2 at the edges and one anywhere in between. By dragging the waypoint that is in between the 2 way points you can get a curve of different curvatures.

Answer (score 1):

Simply paste the following text in the edit style:

> verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;html=1;shape=mxgraph.basic.arc;startAngle=0.7934506846033575;endAngle=0.08601043481131534;fillColor=none;direction=east;perimeter=ellipsePerimeter;rotation=0;

Then, you can make an arc of any angle.